# Regex to match string which starts with or ends with or both

Tags: regex

I want to match string which can have a set of keyword i.e) ALP|STRT|MAT in starting or ending or both

**i.e)**

```
ALP123
123MAT
STRT143MAT
```

**Regex:**

```
 \b(?:ALP|STRT|MAT){0,1}\d+(?:ALP|STRT|MAT){0,1}\b
```

but the regex also matches just numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternation of requiring at the start and optional at the end, or visa versa:

```
 \b(?:(?:ALP|STRT|MAT)\d+(?:ALP|STRT|MAT)?|(?:ALP|STRT|MAT)?\d+(?:ALP|STRT|MAT))\b
```

Note also that `{0,1}` can be replaced with just `?`.